# Real time output showing in RichTextbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, console, runtime, real-time

Is there anyone who can help me to read from console output before the process terminate.

I have a third party console application and his application probably not flushing the data after every line and I'm unable to read from.

Is there any other way rather than using **Process** like Shell or Using Any Windows API to read data from console on run-time?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub StartMiner()

        MinerProcess = New Process

        MinerProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "abc.exe"
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        MinerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        MinerProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--server abc"

        MinerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
        MinerProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()

        MinerProcess.Start()
        MinerProcess.WaitForExit()

End Sub

Private Sub MinerProcess_OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MinerProcess.OutputDataReceived

        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.BeginInvoke(CType(Sub()
                                     RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & e.Data & Environment.NewLine
                                 End Sub, MethodInvoker))
        Else
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & e.Data & Environment.NewLine
        End If

End Sub
```

Also I have tried using **Read** , **BeginRead** , **Readline** , **ReadtoEnd** but nothing working as I need. All methods works, but show output when I terminate the process and console file is long running process so can't close and reopen again for getting output.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make a fileStream set to the process stdOutput
example:

```
Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
```

and you can read *myStreamReader* over and over...

Comment: i did tried mate
but it shows output after the console terminate

Comment: @SunnyGRT so you can check if the process is still alive, right?

Comment: No i can’t check progress live. When the process terminate then it show output.